# How to check cell value in GirdView if value is null then GrieView.Visible.Equals(false)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to checked value of Checkbox in GridView if any rows is null then next GridView can't show.

```
//Checkbox GridView1
        foreach (GridViewRow rowItem in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)(rowItem.Cells[4].FindControl("chkSelected1"));
            if (chk.Checked == false)
            {
                GridView2.Visible.Equals(false);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                GridView2.Visible.Equals(true);
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign false to the visible property. Currently you are comparing it, if it equals false. Do it like:

```
GridView2.Visible = false;
```

Your current code returns a `bool` value, **it doesn't set the Visible property** of the gridview

```
GridView2.Visible.Equals(false);
```

The above line from your code compares if the `GridView2.Visible` property is set to false. It doesn't update the `Visible` property of the gridview.

Similarly to make the Grid View visible set it to true like:

```
GridView2.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView2.Visible = false;

GridView2.Visible = true;
```

will do the job